# Regular expression on TEA lenguaje

Tags: html, templates, encryption

I am doing now a migration of some code developed on the tea lengauje to groovy, I am struggling with some code because I have not experience on Tea.

According with I understand on the tea language there are not regular expressions support and I found the next line of code.

```
realKey = '.*' & key & '(/_/|\\?)?.*';
```

I don't really understand what is the meaning of this code and I can't relate this with a regular expresion.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance